# Why doesn't a deployed app connect to the GraphQL endpoint when the the settings exist in the branch?

Tags: deployment, vuejs2, graphql, aws-amplify

I have a basic VueJS app that connects to a AWS Amplify DynamoDB with GraphQL. Everything connects, data is available to work with locally. The app can also be deployed successfully on a given branch.

However, even with the `aws-exports` file present with the GraphQL endpoint settings, the deployed app doesn't connect to the DB.

```
// WARNING: DO NOT EDIT. This file is automatically generated by AWS Amplify. It will be overwritten.

const awsmobile =  {
    "aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint": "https://xxxxxxx.appsync-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/graphql",
    "aws_appsync_region": "us-east-2",
    "aws_appsync_authenticationType": "API_KEY",
    "aws_appsync_apiKey": "xxxxxxxx",
};

export default awsmobile;
```

Instead accessing the app at this link throws this error:

```
"No graphql endpoint provided."
```

I deployed using AWS Amplify console. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some snooping around I found the fix, and it's pretty simple. It's not enough to have the AppSync settings, we have to actually configure Amplify with the GraphQL endpoints and api key like so:

```
Amplify.configure(aws_exports);
Vue.use(AmplifyPlugin, AmplifyModules);
Vue.config.productionTip = false

Amplify.configure({
  API: {
    graphql_endpoint: 'https://xx.appsync-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/graphql',
    graphql_headers: async () => ({
      'x-api-key': 'xxxx',
    })
  }
});
```